# Find area bounded by curves

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, area

Let $f(x,y)=(1-x-y)^{3}-27xy$ and define the subset $C$ of $\Bbb R^{2}$ by
$$
C=\{ (x,y) \in \Bbb R^{2} \mid f(x,y)=0 \}.
$$
I want to find the area bounded by the $x$-axis, the $y$-axis and $C$. 
It's easy to see that the intersections of $C$ and axes are $(0,1), (1,0)$. To find the area bounded by curves I would think about computing double integrals. However, it's not easy to find the range of $x$ (resp. $y$) in terms of functions of $y$ (resp. $x$). That is if we let $x \in [0,1]$ then it's hard to find $a(x),b(x)$ so that $a(x) \le y \le b(x)$. I had a small observation that $(t^{3},(1-t)^{3})\in C$ for all $t\in \Bbb R$, but I'm not sure whether it has significance here.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Double integrals are for evaluating volumes, not areas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 'small observation' is the key. We have
$$x=t^3$$
$$y=(1-t)^3=1-3t+3t^2-t^3=1-3x^{1/3}+3x^{2/3}-x$$

Now you can just integrate $y$ term-by-term over the interval $[0,1]$.

**Edited to add:**
The OP asks whether this parametrisation covers the whole of $C$. I don't know about that, but it does cover the part of $C$ in the upper right quadrant, which is sufficient for our purposes.

To see this, note that if $x$ and $y$ are non-negative, then $(1-x-y)^3$ is strictly monotonic decreasing in $y$, and $27xy$ is (perhaps non-strictly) monotonic increasing in $y$. So the equation
$$(1-x-y)^3 = 27xy$$
can have only one solution $y$ for a particular $x$.

Comment: Did you mean $C=\{(t^{3},(1-t)^{3}) : t \in \Bbb R\}$?

Comment: @user: Yes, of course.

Comment: It's clear to me that $C \supseteq \{(t^{3},(1-t)^{3}) : t \in \Bbb R\}$. But why $C \subseteq \{(t^{3},(1-t)^{3}) : t \in \Bbb R\}$?

Comment: @user: Oh, I see. You may be right. But it doesn't matter, because your parametrisation does cover the part of the curve from $(0,1)$ to $(1,0)$.

Comment: How do you prove it?

Comment: @user: As $t$ moves continuously from $0$ to $1$, the point $(t,(1-t)^3)$ moves continuously, with increasing $x$ and decreasing $y$, from $(0,1)$ to $(1,0)$. So, along with the axes, it does describe a closed, bounded area But now you want to know whether there is perhaps another component of $C$ in the upper right quadrant? I will think about that!

Comment: Do your explanation above together with your posted answer solve my post? Of course I know if there is no another component of $C$ rather than $\{(t^{3},(1-t)^{3}) : t \in \Bbb R\}$ in the upper right quadrant, then we are done.

Comment: @user: See my edit.